# Convert char array to unsigned char*

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Is there a way to convert `char[]` to `unsigned char*`?

```
char buf[50] = "this is a test"; 
unsigned char* conbuf = // what should I add here
```

Comment: Related: [Why can't I static_cast between char * and unsigned char *?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10151834/4284627)

Answer (score 9):

Although it may not be technically 100% legal this will work `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(buf)`.

---

The reason this is not 100% technically legal is due to section 5.2.10 `expr.reinterpret.cast` bullet 7.

> A pointer to an object can be explicitly converted to a pointer to an object of a different type. original type yields the original pointer value, the result of such a pointer conversion is unspecified.

Which I take to mean that `*reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(buf) = 'a'` is unspecified but `*reinterpret_cast<char*>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(buf)) = 'a'` is OK.

Comment: If I remember the standard correctly, there is an exception that says that it is legal to use pointer to [[un]signed] char to access memory of an object of any type. I think it makes behavior of your code well-defined.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't remember any such wording, if you could supply a reference I'll update the answer.

Comment: Unforunately I'm unable to find a standard reference. But I found some claims on SO that there is an exception to the strict aliasing rule for `char *` (which means that "it is legal to use pointer to [[un]signed] char to access memory of an object of any type"). See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/99010/2752075 `You can use char* for aliasing <...>. The rules allow an exception for char* (including signed char and unsigned char). It's always assumed that char* aliases other types. However this won't work the other way: there's no assumption that your struct aliases a buffer of chars.`

Answer (score 6):

Just cast it?

```
unsigned char *conbuf = (unsigned char *)buf;
```

Comment: in C++, "Just cast it" always needs a disclaimer :)

Comment: Heh-heh! Disclaimer: This answer is fine for the text you show in the question. Don't try it on arrays of signed 8 bit numbers.