# C++ how to convert from char * to unsigned char * in function call?

Tags: c++, casting, char, unsigned-char

When building my C++ application the build fails at this line of code

```
if (!PyTuple_GetByte(poArgs, 0, &SourceCell.window_type))
```

with this error

> error C2664:  'PyTuple_GetByte' : cannot convert parameter 3 from
>   'char *' to 'unsigned char *'

This is the called function:

```
bool PyTuple_GetByte(PyObject* poArgs, int pos, unsigned char* ret);
```

The third parameter `&SourceCell.window_type` is type `char`.

Is there a way to convert/cast the parameter inside the function call like

```
if (!PyTuple_GetByte(poArgs, 0, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&SourceCell.window_type)))
```

or do I have to deal with it in another way?

Comment: Just try it .....

Comment: A `static_cast` should work fine IIRC.

Comment: Did `if (!PyTuple_GetByte(poArgs, 0, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&SourceCell.window_type)))` not work?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think `static_cast` will not work here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151834/why-cant-i-static-cast-between-char-and-unsigned-char as they're different types no?

Comment: The `static_cast` did not work, @πάνταῥεῖ is right. I tried that before. Currently I am trying to use a `reinterpret_cast` but wanted to know if any experts here have a more elegant solution.

Comment: You'd have to `reinterpret_cast` or c-style cast here

Comment: if you can change type of the SourceCell.window_type to be unsigned char instead of a normal char, no cast will be needed

Comment: Safe way is to create an unsigned char buffer, read into it, then assign to the char array from it checking the values.

Comment: @EdChum i.e. you have to `reinterpret_cast`. c-style casts are defined in terms of some `*_cast`s

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert char array to unsigned char\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944436/convert-char-array-to-unsigned-char)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error, the signature of the `PyTuple_GetByte` function was expecting a third parameter of type `unsigned char*`, but you passed a variable of type `char*` at its invocation. I think you have two options here.

1. You can change the signature of function `PyTuple_GetByte` to expect a `char*` parameter.
2. You need to convert your input variable from type `char*` to type `unsigned char*`, before you can pass it into `PyTuple_GetByte`.

The conversion is normally like this:

```
unsigned char* convert_var = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&SourceCell.window_type); // (c++ way)
```

or

```
unsigned char* convert_var = (unsigned char*)(&SourceCell.window_type); // (c way)
```